# How to compute the union of two subsets of integers with LINQ?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

I should solve the task using LINQ:
A positive integer K, an integer D, and a sequence of integers integerList are given.
Compute the union of two subsets of integers: the first subset is all integerList values up to
and excluding the first element greater than D, the second subset is the integerList values
starting with the element with ordinal number K inclusive (integerList element numbering
starts at 0). Sort the resulting sequence in descending order.

I have a test case with a test data for the task:

```
 private IEnumerable<(int k, int d, IEnumerable<int> integerList, IEnumerable<int> expected)> Task8Data()
        {
            yield return (
                k: 3,
                d: 25,
                integerList: new[] { 12, 17, 18, 19, 25, 14, 45, 71, 63, 78, 11 },
                expected: new[] { 78, 71, 63, 45, 25, 19, 18, 17, 14, 12, 11 });
            yield return (
                k: 30,
                d: 1,
                integerList: new[] { 12, 17, 18, 19, 25, 14, 45, 71, 63, 78, 11 },
                expected: new List<int>());
            yield return (
                k: 8,
                d: 1,
                integerList: new[] { 12, 17, 18, 19, 25, 14, 45, 71, 63, 78, 11 },
                expected: new [] { 78, 63, 11 });
            yield return (
                k: 15,
                d: 25,
                integerList: new[] { 12, 17, 18, 19, 25, 14, 45, 71, 63, 78, 11 },
                expected: new[] { 25, 19, 18, 17, 14, 12 });
        }
```

I can't understand why in the last test dataset the expected result is { 25, 19, 18, 17, 14, 12 }.From my point of you, it should be { 25, 19, 18, 17, 12 }, because there are no elements, which are with index K and elements, which are less or equal D are 25, 19, 18, 17, 12. Where is the mistake in my understanding?

Comment: Isn't `11` less than or equal to `25`? Your question seems to have misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the mistake in my understanding?

The description of the problem is **not** asking for
*elements, which are less or equal D   ...*

> the first subset is all integerList values up to and excluding the first element greater than D,

This is asking you to stop **once** you hit the first value greater than d.

i.e. it should be implemented as

`integerList.TakeWhile(a => a <= d)`

whereas I think you are using

`integerList.Where(a => a <= d)`

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right! I used where, but I should use TakeWhile